# Join Multiple tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, join

im new to SQL and want to know how to replace the below code with SQL joins.

I want to list all information based on p_id ='123'.

```
select p.p_name,c.c_name,s.s_name,s.s_contact,b.b_name,b.b_contact 
from product p, category c, seller s, buyer b 
where p.p_id="123" and c.p_id="123" and s.p_id="123" and b.p_id="123";
```

Tables used

**Product Table**

```
p_id
p_name
```

**Category Table**

```
p_id
c_id
c_name
```

**Seller Table**

```
p_id
s_id
s_name
s_contact
```

**Buyer Table**

```
p_id
b_id
b_name
b_contact
```

Thanks

Comment: You are already doing joins, but using an older version of the syntax. Jens' answer has the newer version of the syntax.

Comment: Not related, but : **123 is a NUMBER and not a string**. Using `single-quotation marks` would introduce unnecessary `implicit conversion`.

Comment: And in ANSI SQL "123" is not a string, it's a delimited identifier. (I.e. the column named 123 in this case...)

Comment: @jarlh, If you reread my comment, I said single-quotation and not double-quotation marks. `Oracle` would throw invalid-identifier error. Also read OP's question, he said "*I want to list all information based on p_id ='123'.*"

Comment: @LalitKumarB, yes, and I agree. But after reading your comment I also noticed the "123" in the code example, that's why I wrote my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query using join:

```
select p.p_name,c.c_name,s.s_name,s.s_contact,b.b_name,b.b_contact 
from product p 
join buyer b  on p.p_id = b.p_id and <second condition>
join category c on  p.p_id = c.p_id
join seller s on c.p_id  = s.p_id
where p.p_id="123" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining all the table with your criteria as below:

```
SELECT p.p_name,c.c_name,s.s_name,s.s_contact,b.b_name,b.b_contact 
FROM product p INNER JOIN category c
ON   p.p_id = c.p_id
INNER JOIN seller s
ON p.p_id = s.p_id
INNER JOIN buyer b 
ON p.p_id = b.p_id
WHERE p.p_id='123';
```

Comment: if there is AND condition from product and buyer? how to combine in joins

Comment: it should be like `ON p.p_id = s.p_id AND p.Nextid = s.nextId`